# Cannot use the keyword 'and' in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a bibliography for an article I am writing and am having the problem that when I try to include multiple authors in a reference, the word 'and' is not recognised and gets added on the surname of the first author.  For example:

```
@PREAMBLE{
 "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}" 
 # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%" 
}


@article{Dress2012,

author = {J. Dressel and A. N. Wilson},

title={Significance of the imaginary part of the weak value },

journal = {Phys. Rev. A},

volume = 85,

pages = {012107},

year = {2012},
}
```

In the document the authors appear in the reference as

> J. Dresseland A. N. Wilson.

Edit: I wrote to Overleaf and they fixed the bug in the template so that this no longer occurs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make a compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue can not be reproduced with the information shared in the question (we need to know document class, bibliography/citation packages and bibliography style). Furthermore, the problem appears to have been resolved by Overleaf, so there is nothing to be done here.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: the space you see before 'and' is not a space, but the unicode unbreakable space U+00A0.  Try to delete the character and insert a real space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in my code I have written J. Dressel and A. N. Wilson such that there is a space between the surname and the word 'and'.  When I compile, the space disappears in the PDF document.

Comment: What editor did you use to write text?  Many editors mangle text

Comment: I'm using a RevTeX template on the website Overleaf.  Where would I find the editor which is being used?

Comment: I've checked and it seems to be a bug in a standard template for writing papers for Physical Review and related places on Overlead, the template is RevTeX 4.2 Template and Samples, so there must be something wrong in that template.  If I add in 3 authors, like A and B and C there is no problem, it is just when where are 2 authors.